# restoring error in sql Try Block not being caught

Tags: sql-server, try-catch, database-restore

I have written a stored procedure that restores a database from given .bak file, and scheduled this procedure in SQL Server Agent's Job. Now sometimes what used to happen was that the .bak file was not available, or being copied or scanned by antivirus or God knows what else during my Restore process raising an OS error (file being accessed by another process) (not always but sometimes).
In order to bypass it, I placed my Restore statement in try-catch block within a loop as given below assuming this might solve the problem, but it's not working that way. Following is my procedure :

```
DECLARE @Repeat INT
SET @Repeat = 1

WHILE (@Repeat = 1)
BEGIN
BEGIN TRY       
        IF DB_ID('MyDBName') IS NOT NULL
        BEGIN
            DROP DATABASE MyDBName          
        END

        SET @File = @Path+@File --@File contains valid values, no problem in them
        print @File
        RESTORE FILELISTONLY FROM  DISK = @File
        --print 'Restore Filelist Successful' 

        RESTORE DATABASE BSG FROM DISK =  @File
        WITH REPLACE, MOVE 'ABC_Data' TO 'D:\MyDBName\MyDBName.mdf',            
        MOVE 'ABC_Log' TO 'D:\MyDBName\MyDBName_1.ldf'
        SET @Repeat = 0
        --print 'Restore Database Successful' 
        --print 'Move Successful'       
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH 
    print 'Error Occured'   
    SET @Repeat = 1
END CATCH
END
```

Note that my procedures works fine most of the time say 7/10, but some times when I see the job history I see following error in failure report :

```
Executed as user: NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM. In Transaction [SQLSTATE 01000] (Message 0)
'*MyBackupDBFilePath*' [SQLSTATE 01000] (Message 0)  Cannot open backup device 
'*MyBackupDBFilePath*'. Operating system error 32(The process cannot access the file
because it is being used by another process.). [SQLSTATE 42000] (Error 3201). 
The step failed.
```

I can see some problem was there while accessing my .bak file but what I don't get is why doesn't my procedure try to restore the db again (basically why the failure is not caught by my catch which sets @repeat value to 1

Comment: @usr man they are monsters :P ppl having vote ups greater than my total rep O.O

Answer (score 1):

I have had issues with `TRY CATCH` blocks not tripping when errors were occurring and it had to do with errors that prevented the entire block from executing. For instance, if you have a try catch block for rolling back a transaction in the event of a failure and it encounters a non-existent column. That is not a parsing error, but it is an error that prevents execution and so it just outright fails. I have had success getting such situations to trip the catch block if I include a

`SET XACT_ABORT ON` at the beginning of the script.

[MSDN SET XACT_ABORT settings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188792.aspx)

> When SET XACT_ABORT is ON, if a Transact-SQL statement raises a run-time error, the entire transaction is terminated and rolled back.

Hopefully this helps you. If not, it's still a good idea to use and we use it in our jobs that use `TRY CATCH` blocks just in case a column gets dropped or something like that.

Comment: my scenario is rare, I, however, will try out your suggestion. Won't be able to tell unless I don't encounter the error for coming few days after trying out your method. I'll mark it as answer once done :) Thanks for considering such old question